# Is it possible to install only the profiling feature of Elasticsearch 6.8 X-Pack?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-x-pack

My installation of Elasticsearch 6.8.22 does not include an installation of X-Pack because so far we have not needed any of its features.

I am generating profiling data on queries, using the [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/_tune_your_queries_with_the_profile_api.html),  but I want to use the [Search Profiler UI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.8/xpack-profiler.html) capabilities available in Kibana.  The documentation says that this is part of X-Pack.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to install all of X-Pack in order to use the Search
   Profiler UI, or is it possible to install only certain features?
2. Do
   I have to install X-Pack on the entire Elasticsearch cluster where I
   am running the query in order to profile it?
3. Can I isolate the
   X-Pack installation by creating a new separate Kibana installation
   on its own server and connecting to my cluster, or does the X-Pack
   installation need to be on one or more Elasticsearch servers in my
   cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to 1 is it need to be installed as an entire package

the answer to 2 is yes, the entire cluster

the answer to 3 is no, see question 2